# Is there a way to add fa icons to the css file

Tags: css

We are only using a few fa icons from my font-awesome.min.css. Is there a way to add fa icons to the css file directly? That way only 1 css file would be loading

Comment: try using CDN link, that would be easier. because while using the file you have to download the font files also i.e. ttf, woff, otf files. and without those the fonts wont show, pseudo element is just a escape to not using HTML but you need to link file or CDN

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach :)
You have svg files which
can be injected by css and in html you use your own classes

Here is an example

```
<i class="bb-icon"></i>
```

In the CSS file:

```
.bb-icon {content: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg); width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

Working example:
[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/barbug/pen/NJmOvK)

Here you can also make the svg css ready and put it directly into style sheet
[Make SVG CSS READY](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)

CSS:

```
.bb-icon2 {content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23'%0Axmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%0Axmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%0Awidth='512' height='512'%0Aversion='1.1' id='svg2'%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0,448)'%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%23000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:%23000000;stroke-width:12;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none' d='m 16,256 240,-192 96,72 0,-32 48,0 0,72 96,80 -48,0 0,192 -120,0 0,-160 -96,0 0,160 -168,0 0,-192 z' transform='translate(0,-448)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E"); width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

To change color you need to change fill property or fill style... This is tricky however

Answer (score 0):

add the font awesome link in your header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

now you can use the icons als pseudo elements in your css

you can read more about it here:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: He asked for a solution to avoid loading this stylesheet.

Comment: you need this style sheet otherwise you cant acces the font-awesome library. another way is to download a package and host the files yourself. use the webfonts in your own stylesheet. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself.